# detecting interaction with user in firefox from bash

Tags: bash, firefox

I want to stop firefox if I am using it for more than a given time,so I want to be able to  detect interactive activity and I want manage that from a bash scritp... Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to detect if user **actively** uses firefox for some time "t > X mins"? & not count if it is just lying idle?

It is not possible to detect it with bash, unless you do some intelligent parsing of tcpdump.

You may however, create a firefox addon for the same. Plenty of [help available on internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=create%20firefox%20addon).
You may take [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/timetracker/) as reference.

EDIT: Sorry, I think it should be [possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16131/how-do-i-find-the-x-window-id-under-the-mouse-pointer-in-bash).